# Equivalent pattern to old asp getarray()

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Just moving to .net and trying out c# with razor without MVC, just creating web pages.

I endlessly created this sort of pattern in classic ASP using my own classes which returned arrays..

```
-open connection
-execute SQL
-get recordset
-stick in array (getrows)
-destroy recordset
-close connection
-return array and other stuff such as fieldnames, returned rows check/number and so on from the class.
```

Then in the code I would loop through the array and build the UI and display.

What is the equivalent pattern in .net using c# and razor to do the rendering..? All the examples I see seem to do this in the one code block without really using the datareader to do anything..

```
-open connection
-execute sql
-fill a datareader
-do while and dump to screen
-close/destroy connection/datareader
```

This pattern means I have to use the datareader within the main body of the page to render the required HTML and remember to close/destroy it at the end, which seems to me to be less efficient, but I am probably just not thinking about .net in the right way (still in interpreted script mode)! I also cant use the connection for anything else whilst the one datareader is open, again I am probably doing it incorrectly!

I dont generally use or require all the 'built' in sort of user controls like grid view etc as I find I need to customise them so much it defeats the point to me, Im happy looping through a simple construct like an array or collection.

Rolf

Comment: Use Entity-Framework to handle the talking with the database. Get data from your `dBContext`, loop over it and print it on the screen (possibly transfering to a viewmodel somewhere in between). data retrieval is done with the EF, connection gets handled with the `using(DbContext)` statement, you can just return a collection with the data and all you have left is looping and printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classic ASP, when you get a `RecordSet`, you have an open connection with database, just like `DataReader`. You can read a column at time like `dr["ColumnName"]` or get all column values as an array, using [GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method.

If you need to read all values at once, you can stick with a `DataAdapter` and filling a `DataSet`

About your concern with disposing database connections, you can use `using` statement as it will dispose that connection and return it to framework connection pool.

If you can use a ORM like Entity Framework, it will be in charge when you read your data from your business objects, correctly reading from your database tables, so this is probably a more productive approach.

Comment: wont be able to use Entity Framework at present as all databases are still on 2000. Its also one more thing to learn and one more complication when I am already quite fully complicated =)

Comment: Ok so I just tried this out but using the USING statement, anything within that block is unavailable outside. So what I am left with is opening the connection, stuffing the dataset with my tables/recordsets then closing the connection. Ive read that datasets do not need to be explicitly closed/destroyed, is that the case..? If so I am back to the pattern I'm used to, though it may not be the 'right' one.

Comment: You're right, all variables declared within a `using` block is unavailable outside it. So, you must declare your `DataSet` outside and fill it inside. As a `DataSet` doesn't keep a live connection with your database, I think you have same pattern as classic ASP.